# How to import a tab delimited file in MySQL database using Java?

Tags: java, mysql, csv

I want to import a tab delimited file in MySQL database.  How I can do this using Java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is very vague, but it sounds like a mysql specific question. Here's the [manual for loading files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html). The default is:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY ''
```

Answer (score 3):

**Import a tab delimited file into MySQL:**

1. Create your table:

   ```
   mysql> create table foo(id INT, mytext TEXT, sparkle DECIMAL(9,4));
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
   ```
2. Create your data file, put this in foo.txt, note tabs delimit the 3 columns

   ```
   1   twilight sparkle is best pony!  6.6 
   2   pinkie pie is best pony!    3.3 
   3   derpy hooves is best pony!  1.1
   ```
3. Then import the file:

   ```
   mysqlimport --fields-terminated-by='\t' 
               --columns=id,mytext,sparkle 
               --local -u root -ppassword your_database foo.txt
   yourdatabase.foo: Records: 4  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 3
   ```
4. Look in the table.

   ```
   mysql> select * from foo;
   +------+-------------------------------+---------+
   | id   | mytext                        | sparkle |
   +------+-------------------------------+---------+
   |    1 | twilight sparkle is best pony |  6.6000 |
   |    2 | pinkie pie is best pony       |  3.3000 |
   |    3 | derpy hooves is best pony     |  1.1000 |
   +------+-------------------------------+---------+
   4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
   ```

The rows were loaded.

Read up on my mysqlimport command to see all the things it can do.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [Scanner API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read file and create your dynamic SQL statements. After that use [JDBC preparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and execute them.

Answer (score 0):

Open a JDBC connection to your database. Create a prepared statement to insert a row in your table. Read the file line by line. You might use something like [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to help you. For each line, bind the parameters of the prepared statement and execute it. Close the prepared statement, the connection and the file reader.

Read http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html to learn JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("myfile.tab")));

String line = null;

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] fiedls = line.split("\\t");
    // generate your SQL insert statement here
    // execute SQL insert.
}
```

If you are not familier with SQL and/or JDBC refer to appropriate tutorial. Google will help you to find one.